# Stuff function and how to order the stuff string order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqltransaction

I'm trying to stuff the `Distinct` Column values in the table based on grouping on particular columns, I'm able to stuff the `distinct` values of the column in to single String but the order of the string is not correct when I compare the result that has three stuff results in a row.

And I've used SQL Query as below:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableB (
              AcquireNbr int
            , Working_Day Date
            , Working_Cd varchar(15)
            , Agreement_Cds varChar(60) NULL
            , Agreement_id_Qtys varChar(80) NULL
            , Agreement_Receiver_Cds varchar(80) NULL
            , Agreement_Managers varChar(80) NULL
        )
        INSERT INTO #TableB
        SELECT 
              AcquireNbr
            , Working_Day
            , Working_Cd
            , Agreement_Cds             =   STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Agreement_Cd))
                                            FROM #TableA b 
                                            WHERE b.Working_Cd = a.Working_Cd AND b.AcquireNbr = a.AcquireNbr AND b.Working_Day = a.Working_Day 
                                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
            , Agreement_id_Qtys         =   STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), Agreement_ID) + '_' + CONVERT(varchar(15), Agreement_Qty)
                                            FROM #TableA b 
                                            WHERE b.Working_Cd = a.Working_Cd AND b.AcquireNbr = a.AcquireNbr AND b.Working_Day = a.Working_Day
                                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
            , Agreement_Receiver_Cds    =   STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Agreement_Receiver_Cd))
                                            FROM #TableA b 
                                            WHERE b.Working_Cd = a.Working_Cd AND b.AcquireNbr = a.AcquireNbr AND b.Working_Day = a.Working_Day
                                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

        FROM 
            #TableA a
        GROUP BY 
              AcquireNbr
            , Working_Day
            , Working_Cd
```

**Data Table** `TableA` contains my data, as below

```
AcquireNbr  Working_Day Working_Cd  Agreement_ID    Agreement_Qty   Agreement_Cd    Agreement_Receiver_Cd
5           2018-03-09  ABC         1               246000          FT              E
5           2018-03-09  DEF         2               3300            FT              E1
5           2018-03-09  DEF         3               900             FT              E1
5           2018-03-09  DEF         2               3300            FT              E1
5           2018-03-09  ABC         4               0               NT              80
5           2018-03-09  GHI         5               25000           NT              80
5           2018-03-09  DEF         3               900             FT              E1
```

And the **result for query** looks like below

```
AcquireNbr  Working_Day Working_Cd  Agreement_Cds   Agreement_id_Qtys   Agreement_Receiver_Cds
5           2018-03-09  GHI         NT              5_25000             80
5           2018-03-09  DEF         FT              3_900, 2_3300       E1
5           2018-03-09  ABC         FT, NT          1_246000, 4_0       80, E
```

In the last row of the result the AgreementId and Agreement_Receiver_Cd order doesn't match, that is

> for agreement id = 1 the receiver cd is E but in result set it shows
>   as 80

And

> for agreement id = 4 the receiver cd is 80 but in result set it shows
>   as E

I guess the select statement in stuff -> sub query for getting Agreement_Receiver_Cds is returning the result in different order than other sub query which gets Agreement_id_Qtys.

**Required result**

```
AcquireNbr  Working_Day Working_Cd  Agreement_Cds   Agreement_id_Qtys   Agreement_Receiver_Cds
5           2018-03-09  GHI         NT              5/25000             80
5           2018-03-09  DEF         FT              3/900, 2/3300       E1
5           2018-03-09  ABC         FT, NT          1/246000, 4/0       E, 80
```

Comment: If you want an order you must `order by` to get one.

Comment: I tried to Order By on Agreement ID, that gives me two more extra rows for as there are 5 different Agreement ID's, but the order in String E2,80 remains same again on them

Comment: @RajK . . . Your links don't work (at least for me), so your question doesn't make sense.  Moral?  Include all relevant information directly in the question.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, I've updated the post for image links of tables in text format, Please let me know if you have a better solution to my question above